# What options do I have to pause the download of the updater installer?

Tags: java, install4j

I am looking for a way or suggestions on how I can pause the download of a installer upgrade/installer. Is there a feature where I can stop/resume the download. Is this configurable from the install4j ide or can this be accomplished from the install4j Java API?

Case for pausing the download is if the download of the installer is impacting the application (using up available bandwidth). I will want to pause the download and resume at a later time.

Comment: Can you explain your use case for pausing a download?

Comment: I have updated my question to include the case for pausing a download.

Comment: I've added this to our issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 6.1.4 this is not a supported feature in install4j.